# JavaFX pathTransition run at the same time

Tags: java, javafx

I want to use FX make a small animation like this(see the image -- Bean Machine), 10 balls totally. But I found in my for loop, once I created PathTransition, these circles would run at the same time and then stop at the same pace. So I wonder what is wrong with my code, why does not run the circle one by one and continually?

```
        Trace[] traces = new Trace[10];//this is every circle's trace, I wrote another class to deal with its trace
        PathTransition[] pathTransitions = new PathTransition[10];//this is animation for every circle

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            traces[i] = new Trace();
            pathTransitions[i] = new PathTransition();

            //draw Trace --circle
            Circle MovableCircle = new Circle(300, 40, 5);
            MovableCircle.setFill(Color.color(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()));
            pane.getChildren().add(MovableCircle);
            pathTransitions[i].setDuration(Duration.millis(5000));

            //draw Trace -- trace, in order to observe clearly I draw them in the image. 
            traces[i].DrawTrace();
            pane.getChildren().add(traces[i]);
            pathTransitions[i].setPath(traces[i]);
            pathTransitions[i].setNode(MovableCircle);
            pathTransitions[i].setCycleCount(1);
            pathTransitions[i].play();
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried [`ParallelTransition`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/ParallelTransition.html)? **EDIT**: Reading again, I think I misunderstood you - perhaps you need [`SequentialTransition`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/SequentialTransition.html)

Comment: No, because I just know pathTransition, BTW, could you tell me why it works simultaneously?

Comment: @PanPan `play()` is a non-blocking call. It simply "schedules" the animation to be started. JavaFX is responsible for updating running animations and it does so after the method containing your code has completed.

Comment: @sillyfly Thanks a lot, your [SequentialTransition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/SequentialTransition.html) is awesome, my circle works smoothly!